# Waiting for a Docker container to be ready

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, linker-errors

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    command: ["./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh", "tide_server::5432", "cd /app", "npm install", "npm run start"]
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=tide_server"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I tried following this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and using the following shell script to determine when `postgres` is ready.

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

My node Dockerfile is minimal but I have added it for reference:

```
FROM node:latest

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3030
```

Now when I try to run `docker-compose up` I get the following (after the postgres container is ready:

```
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | ./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: psql: command not found
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | ./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: psql: command not found
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | ./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: psql: command not found
server_1    | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
server_1    | ./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: psql: command not found
```

Now I am not sure if this is a linking issue, or something wrong with my script but I have tried every variation I can think of and have had no luck getting this up/

Comment: you need postgres client inside you "node" app container.

Comment: I had similar issue although my problem was silly, the psql host connection command was wrong ('localhost' as host instead of 'postgres').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `command` in `docker-compose.yml`, the command itself is executed in the container it is declared to start in. Catch my drift?

Your `./setup/wait-for-postgres.sh` is being executed in the container, which has no postgres installed. And you can't change it.

But no, actually you can. Run your script in the postgres container. But if you define `command` in the `database` section, it will override the default `CMD` defined in `postgres:latest`, which is just [`CMD ["postgres"]`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e7222bf98572eec2a7b8875c13825015a163091c/9.6/Dockerfile#L69).

This means, you have to slightly rewrite your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

postgres

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

Comment: I got error when using this script:

./wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: postgres: command not found

Comment: @ronin1184 and you execute it with postgres installed in postgres container?

Comment: My docker-compose.yml file exactly same as Otis Wright's file except command in web service: `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "database", "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

Comment: your problem must be elsewhere, a typo of some sort perhaps?

Comment: I got mistake. I put this command inside web container. But when I move it to postgres container in this simple form: `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db"]` then I got error: `"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.`

Comment: Try googling your new error, it is beyond OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

This will successfully wait for Postgres to start. (Specifically line 6)

```
services:
  practice_docker: 
    image: dockerhubusername/practice_docker
    ports: 
      - 80:3000
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; npm start'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/practicedocker
      - PORT=3000   
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=practicedocker
```

Comment: ./docker-entrypoint.sh: 4: cannot open /dev/tcp/db/5432: No such file